# regex multiple occurence of phrases java

Tags: java, regex

i need a regex expression that can identify if a given text contains two phrases that are close to each other, e.g. 0-5 words apart from each other. One may think that subtracting the index of the two phrases can solve the problem. But that is difficult especially when there are multiple occurrences of the phrases in the text. Here is a toy example with 1 occurrence for each phrase:

For example,

```
         phrase1 = "i eat"
         phrase2 = "red apple"
```

matches with

```
        text1 = "i eat a sweet juicy red apple "
```

as there are only 3 words between the two phrases, but it doesn't match with

```
        text2 = "i eat a sweet juicy orange yesterday. I also like red apples "
```

as there are more than 5 word in between. Is there a simple way to do this? Thansk.

Comment: Regex matches existing text, but in your case it is some logic that describes the text.

Comment: I don't understand the issue, and I especially don't understand people's obsession with using a regex for things like this. Just split the text into words, find the index of the phrases, and see how many words apart the phrases are.

Comment: This question looks a whole lot like one that was deleted say half an hour ago???

Comment: The phrase (small group of *words*) "red apple" does not exist in `text2`. "apple" and "apples" are not the same *word*.

Comment: @nhouser9 as I said at the beginning of the post, what you suggested is difficult as there might be multiple occurrences of the phrases in the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution that worked for me:

```
 Pattern.matches(".*\\b" + phrase1 + "\\W*(?:\\w*\\W*){0,5}?" + phrase2 + "\\b.*", text))
```